# AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid vendor key, can not find appid

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, agora.io

Hi i'm trying to setup agora.io in a react/next typescript project, but i have this error in my console:

> Agora-SDK [ERROR]: [client-a361f] join number: 1, Joining channel
> failed, rollback AgoraRTCException: AgoraRTCError
> CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: flag: 4096, message: AgoraRTCError
> CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid vendor key, can not find appid

and

> Failed to join the channel AgoraRTCException: AgoraRTCError
> CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: flag: 4096, message: AgoraRTCError
> CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid vendor key, can not find appid

This is my App.js

```
import AgoraRTC, { AgoraRTCProvider } from "agora-rtc-react";

const config = { mode: "rtc", codec: "vp8" };
const agoraClient = AgoraRTC.createClient(config);

function App() {
    return (
        <AgoraRTCProvider client={agoraClient}>
            // Here my comonents
        </AgoraRTCProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and here my component where i try Agora

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
    useRTCClient,
    useLocalCameraTrack,
    useLocalMicrophoneTrack,
    usePublish,
    useIsConnected,
    LocalVideoTrack,
} from "agora-rtc-react";

const AppID = process.env.REACT_APP_AGORA_ID; // from agora console
const Token = process.env.REACT_APP_AGORA_TOKEN; // from agora console try primary and secondary certificate

const VideoComponent = () => {
    const client = useRTCClient();
    const { localCameraTrack } = useLocalCameraTrack();
    const { localMicrophoneTrack } = useLocalMicrophoneTrack();
    const [isPublished, setIsPublished] = useState(false);
    const videoRef = useRef < HTMLDivElement > null;

    const ChannelName = `AGORA_CHANNEL_ID_1`;

    useEffect(() => {
        const init = async () => {
            try {
                await client.join(AppID, ChannelName, Token, 120);

                if (localCameraTrack && localMicrophoneTrack) {
                    await client.publish([
                        localCameraTrack,
                        localMicrophoneTrack,
                    ]);
                    setIsPublished(true);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Failed to join the channel", error);
            }
        };

        init();

        return () => {
            localCameraTrack && localCameraTrack.close();
            localMicrophoneTrack && localMicrophoneTrack.close();
            client.leave();
        };
    }, [
        client,
        localCameraTrack,
        localMicrophoneTrack,
        AppID,
        ChannelName,
        Token,
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localCameraTrack && videoRef.current) {
            localCameraTrack.play(videoRef.current);
        }
    }, [localCameraTrack]);

    return (
        <div>
            {localCameraTrack && <div ref={videoRef} className="local-video" />}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AgoraComponent;
```

And the agora project console
[image]

I don't know why i have this error,

Comment: Did you get any clue about this issue? I'm also facing the same issue.